# MS SQL. Тип поля для сохранение текста

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Требуется сохранить некий текст (порядка 100.000 - 150.000 символов) в БД. По идее, вполне подойдут varchar(max) или text. Однако на практике получается что более 45.000 (около) записать не получается. В MSDN говорится про 4 млрд. символов или 2Гб текста. Пробовал и через t-sql, и через EF, результат один и тот же. Что я не так понял?

Comment: А как вы поняли что у вас часть текста не записалась?

Comment: Банальным select'ом. EF вообще ничего не записал в поле, я так понимаю как раз по этой причине, но утверждать не буду

Comment: вы выполняли селект из кода? или из management studio? если что - management studio обрезает результат при выводе, до 65535 символов (настраивается в Options / Query Results / SQL Server / Results to Grid.

Comment: Ваша правда, из кода все норм, спасибо. Осталось разобраться почему же ничего не записалось через EF

Comment: C EF тоже самое. Все хранится как надо, но через обзреватель VS не отображает в поле вообще ничего, если свыше 65к. Оформите, плиз, как отдельное сообщение, что мог принять за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле данные сохраняются корректно, но обрезаются при тестовой выборке в SMSS.

SQL Server Management Studio обрезает результат при выводе, до 65535 символов.

Лимит настраивается в Options / Query Results / SQL Server / Results to Grid, но  65535 - максимальное доступное значение.